# Why getaddrinfo returns service ports even if there's no such service running on server?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

> Given a host name and a service name, `getaddrinfo()` returns a list of
>   socket address structures, each of which contains an IP address and
>   port number.

Usage:  `getaddrinfo("stackoverflow.com", "https", &hint, &ailist)`

But it seems that `getaddrinfo` doesn't check whether the service is running on the server or not. Neither it checks the port. It just returns whatever the default port is.

For example, even if there's no `http` or `https` service running on my server, it returns port `80` and `443`. And for another server, `ssh` is running at port `27000`, but it also returns the default port `22`.

So what's the meaning of calling `getaddrinfo`? It seem to only do a dns resolution.

(I am very confused. The function's functionality doesn't match its name at all...)

A full example. https://www.onlinegdb.com/HJfEGOcRtS
(You can fork the code snippet and try with other runtime arguments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getaddrinfo` function isn't meant to see if a particular service is running.  What it does is a name lookup on both the given host name **and** the given service name, populating a `struct sockaddr` structure suitable for connecting, sending, or binding to an IP/port pair.

The hostname lookup part does the typical check of the local host file as well as a DNS server.  The service name lookup checks the /etc/services file to get the port number associated with the named service.  For example, you'll find the following entry in this file:

```
https           443/tcp
```

So the `ailist` array will contain entries with the IP address(es) of stackoverflow.com and port 443.  You can then pass one of those `struct sockaddr` instances to `connect` to connect to that service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from a relevant man page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html):

```
"The getaddrinfo() function combines the functionality provided by
the gethostbyname(3) and getservbyname(3)"
```

That is, a **host** lookup (which could be from /etc/hosts, then DNS, depending on your config), and a **service port** lookup, usually from /etc/services, but can be from other databases.

There is no requirement for things to be on these addresses and ports, it's strictly a database lookup.

Comment: database lookup... Then it really is a dumb function. Who doesn't know by default `https` is run on `443` , `http` on `80` ,`ssh` on `22` and so on..?

Comment: From a systems administration standpoint, being able to tell your machine, or machines that it can find a service in a different place by changing a central configuration file is awesome. Sadly, many people don't know about /etc/services, so stuff gets hard coded, reducing flexibility.